# Modifying a class that is shared to web service client

Tags: c#, wsdl

I'm working on a project that uses C# ASP.NET SOAP web services for communicating between the server and a client desktop app. One of these web services defines a type that is used as the return type of a couple of functions; as a consequence, the class is also defined in the client's proxy class, that is automatically generated from the WSDL (it is a complex type in the WSDL).

Now I need to change the class on the server side. I am worried that all the users (whose current app consumes the "version 1" of the class) may experience malfunctioning as soon as I publish the new version of the web service (with the "version 2" class). Of course, I can't expect all users to urgently upgrade to the new version of the app once I release the web service.

What can I expect to happen in such a scenario? What can I do to prevent issues, or at least to mitigate them? Can such a change be deployed without disrupting all existing installations?

Comment: One option may be to publish the new version of the web service as a separate web service. The new clients would hit the new service while the old clients continue to hit the old service. Then publish a date for removing the old service allowing users of the old client enough time to upgrade.

Comment: The usual thing here is to maintain `api.example.com/` for old users and ask new users to use `api.example.com/2/`. You need to ensure that the things each one can do to your database are compatible, of course.